# Killed 9: Error when appending Pandas dataframes in list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hdf5

I am trying to go through a folder full of pickle (.pkl) files and combine all the dataframes from the pickle files into one HDF5 file.

However, when I try to append **dfs[]** with 100 data frames, I get a "Killed: 9" error halfway through the for loop. Does anyone know a better way to go about doing this? I want to be able to have all my data in one frame, however it seems difficult since there is a lot of data.. Think 1 billion rows total.

```
dfs = []
count = 0
path = '/Users/srayan/Desktop/Pickle'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.pkl')):
    dfs.append(pd.read_pickle(filename))

df = pd.concat(dfs)
key = 'my_key'
df.to_hdf('merged.h5', key)
```

Comment: In my opinion there is problem too big data. If use only 50 files, solution works?

Comment: Yes, however I will need all 100 data frames in 1 data frame to analyze my data